# StyleCopAnalyzers/SA1313 in a positional record: should be disabled?

Tags: stylecop, c#-9.0

With C# 9, you can do the following:

```
public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName);
```

to define the record `Person`. This is equivalent to:

```
public record Person 
{ 
    public string FirstName { get; init; } 
    public string LastName { get; init; }
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName) 
      => (FirstName, LastName) = (firstName, lastName);
    public void Deconstruct(out string firstName, out string lastName) 
      => (firstName, lastName) = (FirstName, LastName);
}
```

according to [this page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/).

So, the elements `FirstName` and `LastName` act both as a property and an argument for the constructor. As properties, these elements should be capitalized, but if I do it, SA1313 complains: `Parameter '__' must begin with lower-case letter.`.

Is it a problem with StyleCop or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem in StyleCop and [it's been fixed for the 1.2.0-beta.261 release](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/3181).

Comment: 2 years later and the release version of StyleCop.Analyzers is still at 1.1.x!

Comment: I still see `SA1313` with this method underscore name having `<PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.2.0-beta.261">`. I cleaned all bin, obj, vs directories and rebuilt after MS VS restart.

Comment: Example: private static PersistanceOptionsFactory GivenPersistanceOptionsFactorySetup() { static string GetEnvironmentVariable(string _) => ApplicationName; return new PersistanceOptionsFactory(GetEnvironmentVariable); }